# CloudKit metadata source local or remote

Tags: ios, swift, date, metadata, cloudkit

iOS 13, Swift 5

I reading this page and couldn't find an answer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/1462223-creationdate

Is the date/time stamped on my record in the CloudKit metadata sourced from my device or from the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its writing right below the title

*The time when the record was first saved to the server.*

Comment: OK, yes... but is that time taken from the server or the device.

Comment: it's taken from server.

Comment: Excellent, I will check it... if your right I click the green tick